# Dynamically increase circle in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a circle getting bigger and bigger in vanilla javascript/css. I never found how to dynamically make the circle increase of lets say 30px. I figured out how to make it 500px after a click but I can't manage to get the initial size. Maybe its not possible in vanilla JS.
Any help would be welcome.

Below is the code I started to implement:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <title>Ball00n p0p</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #balloon {
        background-color: #FF0000;
        border-radius : 50%;
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
    }
    </style>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <script langage="Javascript">
    function func_chg_size () {
    var divbal = document.getElementById("balloon");


    // var w = divbal.style.width;
    // var h = divbal.style.height;
    // console.log('w = ' + divbal.style.width);
    // console.log('h = ' + divbal.style.height);
    //
    // w += 200;
    // h += 200;
    divbal.style.width += 300 + "px";
    divbal.style.height += 300 + "px";
    }
    </script>
<div onclick="func_chg_size();" id="balloon"></div>
<BR />
<BR />

<!-- <div id="balloon"></div> -->
</BODY>
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand you.
The initial size is set in CSS (in your code)

Comment: @ochi the circle needs to increase by 20px each time I click on it so the initial initial size is 200px but the next initial size would be 220px

Comment: gotcha! I posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to grow the circle, use the `divbal.offsetWidth` and `divbal.offsetHeight`

```js
function func_chg_size() {
  var  divbal = document.getElementById("balloon");

  
  
  divbal.style.width = divbal.offsetWidth + 20 + "px";
  divbal.style.height = divbal.offsetHeight + 20 + "px";
}

function init() {
  var divbal = document.getElementById("balloon");

  divbal.style.width += 30 + "px";
  divbal.style.height += 30 + "px";
}


init();
```

```css
#balloon {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="func_chg_size();" id="balloon"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
 <script langage="Javascript">
    function func_chg_size () {
    var divbal = document.getElementById("balloon");
    divbal.style.width = divbal.offsetWidth + 30 + "px";
    divbal.style.height = divbal.offsetHeight + 30 + "px";
    }
    </script>
<div onclick="func_chg_size();" id="balloon"></div>
```

working fiddle here
https://jsfiddle.net/o0s5b3pe/

Answer (score 1):

Check jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/3zxnoLno/

Your code wont work, because you are trying to read elements style attribute. It doesnt have one. You have defined initial sizes in css rules. That is different. Also you cant simply `+=` to the sizes, because it returns a string with `px` at the end. You can use `parseInt()` to convert to a number, and then do maths on that.